# Angularjs conditionally edit a model

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This seems like a dumb question, but I'm new to web/angular programming don't even know how to google it.  If I have a model that the user can edit with a form, how do I let the user cancel the edit?

Do I backup the old values before the edit, or do I create a copy of the model and let the user edit that?  In the first case, if the user cancels the edit, I guess I have to copy the backed-up values back over the changed model?  In the second case, if the user accepts the edits, I'll have a new copy of the model that's been changed.  Other parts of the model that point to it will need to be updated.

In pseudo-code:

```
foo->bar  // foo is a bigger model and user wants to edit bar
barCopy = bar.copy();  // I realize copy() is not-so-trivial thing
open a form on bar
if edits are cancelled, bar needs to be updated with barCopy
```

or

```
open a form on barCopy
if edits are accepted, foo (and others) is pointing at an out of date bar
```

Is there a better option than either of these?  If not, is there a convention about which one to do in angular?  I don't see a good way to do the copying at the language level - googling this topic yields a lot of discussion and [this very up-voted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/most-elegant-way-to-clone-a-javascript-object).  It's troubling that this basic thing I need to do contains so much weird science.  It makes me think there must be a simpler way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, in my controllers that contain form input I have a model for the form inputs themselves, and when a user 'saves', then I update the actual model (and persist in the background). So:

```
$scope.viewModel = {
   myModel: {name:'test'},
   formInputs: {nameInput: ''}
};

$scope.edit = function(){
   $scope.viewModel.formInputs.nameInput = $scope.viewModel.myModel.name;
}

$scope.save = function(){
   $scope.viewModel.myModel.name = $scope.viewModel.formInputs.nameInput;
}

$scope.cancelEdit = function(){
   $scope.viewModel.formInputs.nameInput = '';
}
```

Comment: I see.  Thank you.  And in that save function, do you just enumerate the values, like a line of code per form input?

Comment: Yes, that would be the simplest way.